# Check if data exist in Javascripts objects with click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a project with json data objects populated from form input, i want to compare a given collection based on the input selection as shown below:

```
Question 1
<input type="radio" name="q30" value="135" id="30"> 
<input type="radio" name="q30" value="133" id="30"> 
<input type="radio" name="q30" value="134" id="30"> 
<input type="radio" name="q30" value="136" id="30"> 

Question 2
<input type="radio" name="q31" value="12" id="31"> 
<input type="radio" name="q31" value="13" id="31"> 
<input type="radio" name="q31" value="14" id="31"> 
<input type="radio" name="q31" value="15" id="31">
```

in my javascripts, i want to populate user response on each question as:

```
var response = [];

Array.prototype.inArray = function(comparer) {
    for(var i=0; i < this.length; i++) {
        if(comparer(this[i])) return true;
    }
    return false;
};

Array.prototype.pushIfNotExist = function(add, comparer) {
    if (!this.inArray(comparer)) {
        this.push(add);
    }
};

$('#form input').on('change', function() {

   var add = {'q': $(this).attr('id'), 'r': $(this).attr('value')}

   response.pushIfNotExist(add, function(e) {
        return e.q === add.q;
   });

   console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
});
```

The above code seems to be working but the only issue is that is not updating the `r` variable on click event.

**Current Output:**
After 3 clicks on different radio in question 1 with value(134, 133, 135):

```
[{"q":"30","r":"134"}]
[{"q":"30","r":"134"}]
[{"q":"30","r":"134"}]
```

**Desired Output:**

```
[{"q":"30","r":"134"}]
[{"q":"30","r":"133"}]
[{"q":"30","r":"135"}]
```

**NB:**

From the above i only want to register one response for each question regardless of number of radio clicks from each question. So, as long as i am clicking options in Question 1 i want to prevent from adding new response document, unless i change to Question 2. Hope its clear now.

May be i am doing something wrong or there is a better way of doing it, please can someone help?

Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate `id` at `input` elements ?

Comment: @guest271314 im using jquery's `$('#exam-form input').on('change', function() {` event to grab a specific `input` `id`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, as the others said, don't use duplicate id values in your HTML. It is in no way a good practice.

```
<div>
    Question 1
    <input type="radio" name="q30" value="135" id="30">
    <input type="radio" name="q30" value="133" id="31">
    <input type="radio" name="q30" value="134" id="32">
    <input type="radio" name="q30" value="136" id="33">
</div>

<div>
    Question 2
    <input type="radio" name="q31" value="12" id="34">
    <input type="radio" name="q31" value="13" id="35">
    <input type="radio" name="q31" value="14" id="36">
    <input type="radio" name="q31" value="15" id="37">
</div>
```

Secondly, I made a slight change to your javascript to be as follows:

```
var response = [];    

    $('input').on('change', function() {
        var add = {'q': $(this).attr('name'), 'r': $(this).attr('value')}
        var added = false;
        for(var i = 0, j = response.length; i < j; i++){
            if(response[i].q === add.q){
                if(response[i].r != add.r){
                    response[i].r = add.r;
                    added = true;
                }
                added = true;                    
            }
        }
        if(!added)
            response.push(add);

        console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
    });
```

It's a little bit messy but it does the work. No duplicate questions is added in the response array here.

Answer (score 0):

The way you have the your HTML currently is the culprit of the issue, you need to have separate unique ids on the elements for the code to work as you have it.

Now if you want all of the 'q' values to be the same you need to grab that attribute and use `.substring(1)` to cut it from the first index moving forward: `'q30'.substring(1)` will equal `'30'`

Like so:

```
Question 1
<input type="radio" name="q30" value="135" id="30">
<input type="radio" name="q30" value="133" id="31"> 
<input type="radio" name="q30" value="134" id="32"> 
<input type="radio" name="q30" value="136" id="33"> 

Question 2
<input type="radio" name="q31" value="12" id="34"> 
<input type="radio" name="q31" value="13" id="35"> 
<input type="radio" name="q31" value="14" id="36"> 
<input type="radio" name="q31" value="15" id="37">
```

I pasted your example in the JSFiddle below, note that I removed the #form selector you has because that was not included in your HTML:

**Bonus**, you don't need to (and generally should not) add those functions to the Array prototype, I cleaned up that as well, the code below is sufficient:

```
$('input').on('change', function(event) {
  var name = $(this).attr('name')
  var add = {'q': name.substring(1), 'r': $(this).attr('value')}
  if (!containsObject(add, response)) {
    response.push(add);
  } else {
    response.pop();
    response.push(add);
  }

   console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
});

function containsObject(obj, list) {
    var i;
    var index;
    for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        if (list[i].q === obj.q) {
            return true;
        } 
    }
    return false;
}
```

[Link to Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/omarjmh/cLucfkp1/14/)

Comment: PS, you need to open the console to see what you are logging on JSFiddle

Comment: its still not archiving what i want, as long as i am clicking options in Question 1 i don't want to add new response document, unless i change to Question 2.

Comment: Its a bit cleaned up, but its still adding to the `response` if i click `input` with `q30`, so not exactly

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't duplicate id's in your html. IDs should be unique across the whole page. You can use the name attribute to identify the input instead.

Replace `$(this).attr('id')` with `$(this).attr('name')` and make a slight change in your comparison function like so.

```
response.pushIfNotExist(add, function(e) {
   return e.q === add.q && e.r === add.r;
});
```

Here's the [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/FiIr6ZmvChsx9AtBI169)